# Unkown type name "Enemy" error after including all headers in C

Tags: c

I'm developing a game with `SDL 2.0` in C and I have the following problem: After including all the needed .h files on each file, the compiler shows an error (`unknown type name 'Enemy'`) on `shoots.h`, where I have a function with a parameter of type Enemy declared on enemy.h.

The header files where I think I'm getting the error are bullet.h, enemy.h, mobs.h, and shoots.h. (There are more like `sdl.h`)

bullet.h

```
#ifndef BULLET_H_INCLUDED
#define BULLET_H_INCLUDED
#include "sdl.h"

typedef struct Bullet *Bullet;

#endif // BULLET_H_INCLUDED
```

enemy.h

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H_INCLUDED
#define ENEMY_H_INCLUDED
#include "sdl.h"
#include "shoots.h"

typedef struct Enemy *Enemy;

#endif // ENEMY_H_INCLUDED
```

mobs.h

```
#ifndef MOBS_H_INCLUDED
#define MOBS_H_INCLUDED
#include "enemy.h"

typedef struct EnemyList *EnemyList;
typedef struct EnemyPosition *EnemyPosition;

#endif // MOBS_H_INCLUDED
```

shoots.h

```
#ifndef SHOOTS_H_INCLUDED
#define SHOOTS_H_INCLUDED
#include "sdl.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "bullet.h"
#include "enemy.h"


typedef struct BulletList *BulletList;
typedef struct BulletPosition *BulletPosition;

void initEnemyShoots(BulletList l, BulletPosition p, Player pl, Enemy e);

#endif // SHOOTS_H_INCLUDED
```

struct Enemy declaration on enemy.c

```
struct Enemy {
    SDL_Surface *sprite;    //Enemy sprite
    int x, y;             //Enemy position
    int w, h;               //Enemy hitbox
    BulletList ammo;      //Enemy bullets
};
```

Those headers also have the declaration of functions implemented on each .c file. All structs are defined on his own .c

That initEnemyShoots is where I have the problem, since one of it's parameters is type Enemy. How can I solve that?

Comment: How do you use those `.h` files? Any subdirectories? How do you compile?

Comment: I have added the struct Enemy above

Comment: How are you compiling and what's the error msg?

Comment: All the files are in the same folder, I'm compiling as Standard C99

Comment: That's the error:   error: unknown type name 'Enemy'

Comment: You should remove `#include "shoots.h"`` from enemy.h

Comment: move the struct Enemy declaration from enemy.c to enemy.h.  Ensure enemy.c #includes enemy.h.  Enjoy

Comment: Please note that typedef:ing away pointers is considered bad practice. Instead implement your incomplete type as `typedef struct Enemy Enemy;` and use a pointer to incomplete type in the rest of the code, `Enemy*`. _Do not_ listen to people telling you to move the struct declaration to the h file: that makes everything public and you will toss private encapsulation & good programming practice out the window.

Comment: @Vorsprung No he should _not_ do that. He is attempting private encapsulation with incomplete ("opaque") type, which is very good programming practice. Spamming out a private struct definition into the public by declaring it in the h file is bad program design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by #including "shoots.h" in enemy.h

The `#include "shoots.h"` comes after `#define ENEMY_H_INCLUDED`, however it comes before the actual declaration of `Enemy` as a pointer to a `struct Enemy`. Therefore inside shoots.h `Enemy` is not yet defined, but `ENEMY_H_INCLUDED` is, so even though shoots.h #includes enemy.h, the include guards prevent it from being evaluated and `Enemy` never gets defined.

The solution is just to not include "shoots.h" from inside enemy.h if you don't need to.

Comment: This is most likely the cause. If one ever finds oneself having two h files that include each other, the fundamental program design is broken.

Comment: Right.  And as a general rule, any header or source file should `#include` exactly those headers needed for correctly interpreting its contents, *and no others*.  That doesn't necessarily save you from problems such as the OP's, but it helps, and it makes your headers more easily used.

Comment: @samgak Solved thanks! That was driving me crazy, after a while coding you don't even see those little things.

Answer (score -2):

Your definition of type `Enemy` should be placed in the `enemy.h` header instead of the `enemy.c` module. This way, the type is visible to any module that uses the definition.

UPDATE: apparently, this is an inaccurate advice. See comments below.

Comment: Nope.  There's nothing wrong with the definition of `struct Enemy` not being provided to users of *type* `Enemy`, which works out to be equivalent to `struct Enemy *`, as long as those users don't try to dereference it.

Comment: The whole point of having it in the C file is to _not_ make it visible to other modules who shouldn't be messing with it. What you are proposing is to toss out all good program design just to make the program link... bad idea. The problem isn't related to this anyhow, see samgak's answer.

Comment: @Lundin - but anyway, what do you mean by "messing with it"? If one does not need to use it, then he can just ignore the fact that it is in the header. No need to "mess" with it. Or, did I miss your point?

Comment: @ysap http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: @Lundin - thanks for pointing me to an explanation of encapsulation.... but what do you mean by "messing with it"? Why would one "mess" with a definition of a type in a header file?